# Copy picture to folder and rename the copy with numbers from 1, sequentially

Tags: c#, image, numbers, copy

Here is all I want to do: Every time the button is clicked, an openfile dialog is opened, the user clicks on a picture, then this picture is copied to a specific folder and renamed to a number. Every picture's name in this folder should be a number, but they must all be different. My code so far:

```
if (openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                File = Image.FromFile(openfile.FileName);
                pictureBox3.Image = File;

                int i = 0;
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(picturedir + "\\" + i.ToString() + ".png") == true)
                {
                    i++;
                    MessageBox.Show(picturedir + "\\" + i.ToString() + ".png" + ".....Already Exists.");

                }
                else if (System.IO.File.Exists(picturedir + "\\" + i.ToString() + ".png") == false)
                {
                    System.IO.File.Copy(openfile.FileName, picturedir + "\\" + i.ToString() + ".png", true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

Of course here, the first picture is copied and renamed to "0.png" but the next pictures are not copied at all, because the "if" gives true. Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Do the names have to be sequential, or do they just have to be different.  For example, if you took a 128 bit random number (using `RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes`), you'd get a *really* big number that would be unique as a GUID is (where really bit is about 39 digits).  If you can live with hex numbers, it would be 32 digits long.  Or, you could just use a GUID

Comment: If you can't keep track of the numbers used so far, you could use a `while` loop that keeps checking until it finds a name that does not exist.

Comment: no, I want them to be sequential. So that each new picture is the next bigger number, but I'd also prefer the code to start checking from the beggining each time, so that if a picture is removed, then the new added picture will take its number (as a name of course) instead of just going with the next number as normal. I hope I explained well enough what I mean ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
...
int i = 0;
while (System.IO.File.Exists(picturedir + "\\" + i.ToString() + ".png") == true)
{
    i++;
    // I wouldn't show that message each time, gonna get pretty old for lots of pics!
}
System.IO.File.Copy(openfile.FileName, picturedir + "\\" + i.ToString() + ".png", true);
...
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to do, it works like a charm! Plus, if e.g. there's 0.png, 1.png, 2.png and I delete 1.png, then the next picture will be named 1.png ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the next number, you can enumerate the existing files, find the maximum number now in use and add 1. Something like:

```
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(myCurrentDirectory, "*.png");
    var fileNumStrings = from file in files select Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    var max = 0;
    foreach (var fileNumString in fileNumStrings)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(fileNumString, out var filenum))
        {
            if (filenum > max)
            {
                max = filenum;
            }
        }
    }
    var nextNum = max + 1;
```